# How to automate commit in Azure Databricks Repos?

Tags: git, azure

I am using Azure DevOps Services to add my repo from Databricks. I usually commit every time, but miss a few times. Is there any way in which I could commit automatically the notebooks directly from Databricks to Azure Repos? Also, I could not find any bash script or anything that I can schedule to commit it daily.

Answer (score 0):

Databricks Repos lets you use Git functionality. So its should be straight forward to write a custom script.

Or you can use the Databricks Repos API and you can integrate with your CI/CD pipeline.

You can read more and configure as per your need. Here is the link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/repos/